# expected primary token before s1

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am new to qt creator.
there is an error in gui.cpp

> 24: error: expected primary-expression before 's1'
>        n=string1::len(QString s1);

gui.cpp

```
#include "gui.h"
#include "ui_gui.h"
#include "string1.h"

gui::gui(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::gui) {
    ui->setupUi(this); }

gui::~gui() {
    delete ui; }

void gui::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    QString q1;
    string1 *s1;
    int n;
    q1=ui->lineEdit->text();
    s1=new string1(q1);
    n=string1::len(QString s1);
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(q1); }
```

gui.h

```
#ifndef GUI_H
#define GUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include<string1.h> namespace Ui { class gui; }

class gui : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit gui(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~gui();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::gui *ui; };

#endif // GUI_H
```

string1.cpp

```
#include<string1.h>

string1::string1(QString q1) {
    q=q1; } string1::string1() {
    q=" "; }

int string1::len(QString *s) {
    int i=0;
    while(s[i]!=0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    i--;
    return i; }
```

string1.h

```
#ifndef STRING1_H
#define STRING1_H

#include<qstring.h>
#include<gui.h>


class string1 {
    QString q;

public:
    friend class gui;
    string1 *s1;
    string1();
    string1(QString q1);
    int len(QString *s);

};

#endif // STRING1_H
```

Comment: Are you attempting to perform a cast to `QString`?

Comment: I want to store the length of the string in variable n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by `n=string1::len(QString s1);`, which is declaration of `QString s1` inside the argument list. You probably copied the function declaration from the string1.cpp, changed the parameter name to the argument name, but forgot to remove the type. But it still won't work as `string:::len` is not `static`.

Are sure you need `s1` to be dynamically allocated? It's local variable and you forgot to `delete` before the function ends. If you're using dynamically allocated `string1` just to pass it to `string1::len` avoiding copying, google C++ references.

Comment: What if i replace n=string1::len (QString s1); with n=len(s1);

Comment: Won't work if `len` is still member function. Just put `static` before declaration (not definition).

Comment: Expected primary token before s1

Comment: @slick-holms Did you change it to `n=string1::len(s1);`? Also, as I've mentioned, use references, pointers for `QWidget`s/`QObject`s only.